# How to cloth sculpt with collisions

Tags: sculpting, cloth-simulation

In this blog post they show an example with the cloth brush and collision: https://code.blender.org/2020/10/cloth-sculpting-improvements-in-blender-2-91/

This is the video of where they show it:
https://code.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Cloth_Collisions.mp4

I was wondering, how can I achieve this? I can't grab with that tool for example.
Sorry my question is a bit vague, I don't have the vocabulary nor knowledge to express what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select collider object (sphere) and under *Physics Properties* enable **Collision**

[image]

- Select cloth object (plane), switch to Sculpt mode, take **Cloth Filter** brush and go to
  *3Dview editor > Properties panel (N) > Tool tab > Active Tool >* **Use Collision**

[image]

or with **Cloth** brush go to
*3Dview editor > Properties panel (N) > Tool tab > Brush Settings >* **Enable Collision**

[image]

In video is also for *Grab* type used smaller *Radius* and big *Simulation Limit*.

---

To get gravity behaviour as seen in video ... go to same *Tool* properties tab and increase
*Options >* **Gravity > Factor** like 0.1

[image]