# Transpose cloth tool like in Zbrush?

Tags: sculpting, cloth-simulation, zbrush

I starting to get more into the sculpt tab of Blender, and I wonder if there is a tool to do thing like this: https://www.instagram.com/p/Cjf5jLyr3Q4/?hl=fr

My question is about the cheese: sure, I could just put a plane and sculpt the borders. But is there a way to do it like in the video? By just moving it into a collider object without having to run a cloth sim?

With vanilla Blender or with an addon.

Thank you!

Comment: Does it answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203754/how-to-cloth-sculpt-with-collisions

Comment: @moonboots oh! it look like this will do the job! Thank you very much