# How to make a trash can with a plastic bag?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

[image]

I want to have a plastic bag going on the sides all the way to the bottom like in images 2 & 3.
I think to do it, i need to use cloth physics, but every time i used cloth physics it wouldn't wrap around the edges or it start spazzing out and eventually fly out.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are images 2 & 3 reference images?

Comment: Images 2 & 3 are reference images

Comment: do you want an animation or "just" that reference image as result?

Comment: Just the reference image, so no animation.

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/203829/35559) may help .. you can cloth-sculpt with collisions... and with an irregular starting mesh, it might look more plastic-y and less rubbery.

Answer (score 7):

You can create these 2 objects:

[image]

Give *Collision* physic to the cylinder, give *Cloth* physic to the bag, here are the settings:

[image]

Here is what it gives once animated, stop it at the frame that suits you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for all your help, i finally got it to work.

Answer (score 4):

i would try it with this setup as a beginning:

[image]

C: subdivided plane and cloth

B: collision modifier with low friction, animate it moving down a bit in the can

A: torus as helper object for better bending results with collision modifier and low friction

D: cylinder as basket with collision and low friction

result looks like this:

[image]

unfortunately my Blender file is too big to provide it here.

General hints:

If the cloth acts real weird, often just an upscale of all (x10) can solve the problem.

Comment: What do i do with object B?

Comment: i am sorry, i updated my answer -> animate it a bit down in the can. It should be clearly smaller than the can bottom

Comment: For some reason object B goes right through the plane despite having collision on