# Model objects inside a plastic bag

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to model random objects inside a plastic bag.

Reference:

[image]

Can someone give me some tips about this? I've only seen tutorials with shrinkwrap but I think that's not the case for this.

Thank you

Comment: Might help: [How to do a vaccuum sealed pack?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/125116/78972), [How to make a trash can with a plastic bag?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/293177/78972)